Paste data into all workbooks in a SharePoint folder
I'm trying to copy data from a single Excel workbook into an existing tab into all workbooks in the same SharePoint location with a specific naming criteria.
I need to:

Copy the data in a specified range in the source workbook
Paste the data into every workbook that meets a specific naming criteria, in the same location as the source file, into a specified tab
The file location will change each month.
Many users, who have access to the SharePoint location, need to use the macro.

I'm aware that the Dir() function won't work with SharePoint locations. What do I replace this with?
Sub Copy_To_All_FBS()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    'setting definitions for copy area
    Dim sourceWS As Worksheet
    Dim fRow As Long
    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim CopyArea As Range
    Dim MthName As String
    
    Set sourceWS = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Automation")
    
    fRow = sourceWS.Range("B:C").Find(What:="Type", LookIn:=xlValues).Row + 1
    lRow = sourceWS.Range("S" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Set CopyArea = sourceWS.Range("B" & fRow & ":T" & lRow)
    MthName = sourceWS.Range("Reporting_Month")
    
    'setting files to be copied to
    Dim LoopFolder As String
    Dim destFBSname As Variant
    Dim allFiles As New Collection
    
    LoopFolder = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path & "/"
    Debug.Print LoopFolder
    destFBSname = Dir(LoopFolder & "*.xlsm")
    
    'add all files that start with the reporting month to the file collection
    Do While destFBSname <> ""
        If Left(destFBSname, 3) = MthName Then
            allFiles.Add destFBSname
            destFBSname = Dir
        End If
    Loop
    
    'loop through all files in the collection and copy the source data to each target file
    Dim DestWB As Workbook
    Dim DestSht As Worksheet
    Dim PasteRange As Range

    For Each destFBSname In allFiles
    
        Set DestWB = Workbooks.Open(fileName:=(LoopFolder & destFBSname))
        Set DestSht = DestWB.Worksheets("C07")
        Set PasteRange = DestSht.Range("A3")
        
        'First clear data from target worksheet
        DestSht.Range("A3:Z10000").ClearContents
        
        CopyArea.Copy PasteRange
        DestWB.Save
        DestWB.Close
        
    Next
        
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
End Sub


This is specifically a Sharepoint question, perhaps better asked at Sharepoint SE where people have access to a Sharepoint installation where they can test their code.
